# В функции расшифровки таится баг

Tags: c++

В общем, я пишу *алгоритм шифра цезаря*.

Но в коде функции расшифровщика **decode()** спрятался **баг**...

Например, если я кодирую слово `hello world` с ключом 10, то **encode()** возращает `rovvy gybvn`, НО **decode()** `hello  old`.

И что главное я заметил, чем больше значение ключа, тем больше **decode()** съедает букв.

К примеру: `hello world` с ключом 20 **decode()** возращает вообще  `e d`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string* encode(string* w, int k, string chars) {
    string res = *w;

    for (int i = 0; i < w->size(); ++i) {
        if (res[i] != ' ') {
            int p = chars.find(res[i]);
            res[i] = chars[p + k];
        } else {
            res[i] = res[i];
        }
    }
    *w = res;
    return w;
}

string* decode(string* w, int k, string chars) {
    string res = *w;

    for (int i = 0; i < w->size(); ++i) {
        if (res[i] != ' ') {
            int p = chars.find(res[i]);
            res[i] = chars[p - k];
        } else {
            res[i] = res[i];
        }
    }
    *w = res;
    return w;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string word;
    int key = 0;
    string chars;
    for (char n = 97; n < 123; ++n)
        chars += n;
    chars += chars;

    cout << "Word >> ";
    getline(cin, word);
    string *pword = &word;
    cout << word << endl;
    cout << "Key (0-25) >> ";
    cin >> key;

    encode(pword, key, chars);
    cout << *pword << endl;
    decode(pword, key, chars);
    cout << *pword << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я полагаю, что баг происходит из-за того, что chars[p - k] может выйти за пределы chars, но это не точно.

Comment: общие замечания по коду: в цикле строке chars лучше бы символы сразу присваивали а не код символа, не понятно зачем указатели здесь применяете, передачу обьектов в ф-ию по ссылке следует делать, возвращать по значению у вас достаточно

Comment: Указатели нужен для того чтобы изменить изначальный word

Comment: тогда лучше по ссылке все-таки передавать

Comment: Я немного не понял что вы хотите донести: "в цикле строке chars лучше бы символы сразу присваивали а не код символа"

Comment: Что в цикле chars не так?

Comment: chars += 'a' читаемость увеличит и нет зависимости от кодировки

Comment: Хорошо, а что вы можете сказать, исходя из моей конкретной проблемы?

Comment: выход за пределы массива возможен в фии encode в chars, должно переходить далее в начало алфавита и оттуда буквы брать когда у вас 'w' + 9 это какая буква будет

Comment: Об этом я позаботился, прибавив к chars само же себя

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было в **decode()** начинать искать символ с 25 элемента в **chars**.

```
string* decode(string* w, int k, string chars) {
    string res = *w;

    for (int i = 0; i < w->size(); ++i) {
        if (res[i] != ' ') {
            int p = chars.find(res[i], 25);
            res[i] = chars[p - k];
        } else {
            res[i] = res[i];
        }
    }
    *w = res;
    return w;
}
```